# How to enable View translate and Zoom widgets/gizmo for Node View

Tags: transforms, gizmo

Before I attempt to write a replica widget/gizmo for NodeView. I want to know if there is a simple way to enable this glorious gizmo in a 2d view like NodeView.

[image]

I need these because the trackpad on this laptop is a bit awkward compared to a mouse. The scrollbars are also (whilst aesthetically pleasing) not ergonomic for my situation.

Comment: Node Editor don't have it, but the UV Image editor does curiously. Maybe that is easier to adapt from since it is also a 2D View

Comment: cool. i'll check it out!